# Using blender from PyDev

Tags: python, pydev, blender

I want to to be able to use the blender code directly from PyDev in Eclipse, so I could leverage the blender module to create 3D objects while also using some of my own code. I already followed the steps below to build blender in my windows machine so I could use blender as a module.

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule

Now I am actually trying to code in PyDev, but I am having issues getting it to work.

My code in PyDev is the following.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from math import sin, cos, radians

x = -3
y = -5
z = 3

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=1, view_align=False, 
enter_editmode=False, location=(x, y, z), layers=(True, False, False, False, 
False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
False, False, False, False, False))
```

And I get the following error when I run int in PyDev:

> 'Error: Not freed memory blocks: 8, total unfreed memory 0.008392 MB
>   AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz
>   instead'

If I run the same code inside of blender itself it creates a plane as expected. It is my understanding that after building blender as a py module, I should be able to run the code in pyDev itself.

I was wondering if anyone had a sample blender code that they used in pyDev and worked, just so that I can test it pyDev and see if it creates something in blender. It could be something simple as creating opening blender from PyDev or creating a plane from PyDev itself. I already tried looking for samples, but all that I found was running python in blender, and I want to do the opposite which is running blender in python.

I am pretty new at this so it is very possible that I am missing something in my code.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is two messages joined together, the first about unfreed memory is more of a debugging report, while the other is from the [openal audio settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/77857/935). Both can be ignored. The memory error message gets printed as blender quits, which means the script has been run and the python interpreter that ran the script has been closed, this also means any blender data you created has been freed.

For more persistent data you would want to [open](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile) and [save](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile) a blend file.

To show that you did create the plane add the following to the end of your script -

```
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    print(o.name, o.location)
```

You can find some info on using pydev/pycharm with blender [here](https://code.blender.org/2015/10/debugging-python-code-with-pycharm/), which shows setting up remote debugging so you can run a script within blender. Also you can get blender specific python help at [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you so much! I see that it did create the plane after I added the print statement.